# NSXMLParser leaking

Tags: iphone, ipad, memory-management, memory-leaks, nsxmlparser

Here i am trying to parse the xml data coming from server side of my application. But this code is showing a leak on instruments.

TPatient is NSObject with following variable:
        FirstName,LastName,BirthDate,Phone,Email,Password,Chart,Referredby,RecordConsult,Doctor,Assistant,Notes,PatientStatus,PatientUUID.

```
-(NSMutableArray *)FromXML:(NSString *)xmlstring
{

    curr_patient = nil;
    self.curr_patient_array = nil;
    last_string = nil;
    NSData *data = [xmlstring dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    [xmlParser setDelegate:self];

    [xmlParser parse];
    [xmlParser setDelegate:nil];
    [xmlParser release];


    if(curr_patient!=nil) {
        [curr_patient release];
        curr_patient=nil;
    }


    if(last_string!=nil)
    {
        [last_string release];
        last_string=nil;
    }
    while ( PARSE_STATE == 0 )
        ;

    if ( PARSE_STATE == 1 ) {
        if ( self.curr_patient_array!= nil ) {
            [self.curr_patient_array release ];
            self.curr_patient_array = nil; 
            return nil; 
        }

    }
    if ( self.curr_patient_array == nil )
        return nil;

    return [self.curr_patient_array autorelease];

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser*)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)
elementName namespaceURI:(NSString  *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:
(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary  *)attributeDict

{


    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"Patients" ] == YES )
    {
        if(self.curr_patient_array !=nil)
        {
            [self.curr_patient_array release];
            self.curr_patient_array=nil;
        }
        self.curr_patient_array = [NSMutableArray new ];
    }
    else if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"Patient" ] == YES )
    {

        if ( curr_patient != nil )
            [curr_patient release ];

        curr_patient = [TPatient new ];

    }

}



-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser*)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
 namespaceURI:(NSString*)
namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName

{


    NSString *curString;
    if(last_string==nil)
    {
        curString=@"";
    }
    else
    {
        curString=last_string;
        [curString retain];
    }
    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"Patientid" ] == YES )
    {
        NSInteger it = [ curString intValue];
        curr_patient.PatientId = it;

        [last_string release ];
        last_string=nil;

    }
    else if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"Patient" ] == YES )
    {
        [self.curr_patient_array addObject:curr_patient ];
        [curr_patient release];
        curr_patient = nil;     
    } 

    [curString release];


}


-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{

    last_string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@"
                   ,string];
    [last_string retain];
}
```

Can anyone help me to find the memory leak in following code.

Comment: Too much code. You need to do some more work to tell us what is leaking. Then vanilla the code until you can identify where it is leaking.

Comment: Instruments is showing the leak on the object declaration curr_patient=[TPatient new] in didstartElement section. And also showing a leak for last_string in foundCharacters section

Comment: check this and get some idea please : http://gigaom.com/apple/tutorial-build-a-simple-rss-reader-for-iphone/

Comment: The sample code given in this link is leaking. My parsing is working fine but the problem is with memory leak in my code. @Narayanan

Comment: Hey i think the trouble is because of these two lines **[xmlParser setDelegate:nil];
[xmlParser release];** and yea does it lead to crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
self.curr_patient_array = [NSMutableArray new];
```

To:

```
NSMutableArray *newPatientArray = [NSMutableArray new];
self.curr_patient_array = newPatientArray;
[newPatientArray release];
```

Also `curr_patient = [TPatient new];` could end up being a problem.  Every time you call this line you need to be sure to release it somewhere.  You might want to switch it to a synthesized variable like the NSMutableArray above and allocate it the same way.

And read this: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447

Note that `[NSObject new]` is the same as `[[NSObject alloc] init]`.